# Get values from 2 rows of a table and combine them as a string

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get 2 fields from 2 rows of a table and combine them to be a string. For example:

```
        username    id     text    
row 1   Jason       1      ......
row 2   Lass        2      ......
```

Basically I would need to get `$usernames=Jason, Lass`.

What I've tried:

```
$username_raw=$this->db->select('username')->get('user', 2);

foreach ($username_raw->result() as $row):
echo $username
endforeach;
```

But the last 3 rows turned out not to be working and i'm kinda stuck here. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the complete PHP including the mysql query?

Comment: Have you tried something to combine them within the foreach loop like echo $username.', ';?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stab in the dark tells me this is a [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) question - you should tag that so people know how your query is working. Anyway, your `$username` variable is not initialized. You'll need to access it by `$row->username`.

I suggest you add the usernames to an array, [then `implode()`](http://php.net/implode) the results:

```
$username_raw=$this->db->select('username')->get('user', 2);
$usernames = array();

foreach ($username_raw->result() as $row):
    $usernames[] = $row->username;
endforeach;

$your_usernames_combined = implode(', ', $usernames);

echo $your_usernames_combined; // e.g. Jason, Lass
```

If you want the period at the end like your example, add `$your_usernames_combined .= '.';` to the end.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Gracias Milleu! Exactly as you said, this is a CodeIgniter question and I updated the tags to reflect this. Thanks for pointing this out and thanks for everyone else.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using the Codeigniter framework, you need to use `$row->username` instead.

Then you need to use an array to store the usernames.

Answer (score -2):

I would probably use the "sprintf" function, and the code will look like this

```
    $username = sprintf("%s, %s",$value1,$value2);
```

Your question is pretty unclear, and i dont completely understand where you make calls to your MySQL database, i can only see you calling for the 2nd username

Comment: How are you sure he's calling the second user? We don't know the class structure he's using, so that could be the number of rows to return as well...

Comment: Im not sure of that, i guess i just assumed